# Eliminate Email Blacklist by switching IPs and Servers

Tags: email, exchange-2003, windows-server-2003-r2, blacklist

We are a legitimate company. We have had some issues in the past with Virus attacks/ Spam bots getting our email server blacklisted.

After the most recent attack I have been tasked at coming up with a solution that would allow us to, once determined we are blocked, switch over to a clean server and IP

Here is how my superiors expect this to work... (I feel with the way email is setup and monitored by the blacklists this may not work as they expect.... though the blacklists do function on IP and not domain name....)

Determine which computer or exchange server is infected.
Move to clean exchange server or remove infected computer from network
Switch the company over to a functional and virus free exchange server. (a secondary is standing by)
Switch the exchange server to a secondary IP address to avoid blacklisting.

The idea here is to move to a clean virus free server and an unblocked IP.

Questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. Will we just be blocked again? (let's assume we are not sending out spam on the secondary server and IP)
3. How can I accomplish moving the users from one exchange to the other. Moving mailboxes takes a LONG time. Both exchange servers are on site (physically beside each other)
4. With email reputation as heavily weighted as it is. Is it reasonable to expect email sent from the secondary IP to reach the users Inbox?

They expect this to take under 30 minutes to make the switch from (worst case) infected exchange server with blocked IP to clean exchange server with clean IP.

Server 2003 R2
Exchange 2003 SP2
Active Directory

Assistance/Advice/ or Alternatives are ALL Appreciated!
Thanks everyone,
Campo

EDIT:
Every Machine has AVG

The Exchange Server is not an open relay and requires Authentication

I have done every step and taken every precaution and we still were infected.

EDIT:
BLOCKED AGAIN

new virus name (GRUM)

This is not on our exchange server. No way, scanned with so many things. Went through the registry myself. NOTHING! 
Scanned all other server NOTHING
scanned user computers NOTHING
WTF?

Odd thing is email still goes through but we are on the CBL....

Moved SMTP to non standard port.
Explicitly blocked port 25 on firewall.
delisted us.

**UPDATE:**

**I added additional IPs. Now how do I connect the users on one IP to the server on the other IP? Do I just have the Exchange server have 2 IPs (one for each internal network) or is there more to it?**

**UPDATE 2**

This is a reply to @Madboys comment under his answer:

I have not done it yet. here is the setup. WE now have 5 IPs. I will use 2 for now. 1 for office network. 1 for exchange. Our modem contains both IPs sent to one port on the back of the machine. That LAN cable goes into a switch which then splits into 2. Each goes into our modem (dual Wan RV042) I assign the exchange to one subnet. Network to the other. Please confirm this plan. Ideally a PIX or similar FW appliance would be best. But again 0 dollars must be spent. Question is how will users on one subnet talk to the other? Should I set this up differently? Completely separate networks?

**UPDATE 3**

****OK I was able to do this. Modem to switch then I have 3 cables out of the switch. 1 Goes to a WRT54G for wireless and to separate outside consultants on their own network (they have no reason to be on ours). The other two cables go to my RV042 which supports Dual WAN. I setup a second sub-net. Now how to I isolate each WAN on its own sub-net? I believe the point of Daul WAN on this appliance is to maintain up time by utilizing separate ISPs.... Please assist. WE ARE SO CLOSE please advice
ALSO: I do not see ANY outbound connections on PORT 25 other than from the exchange server. So that is good. And from the exchange the port 25 traffic is at a normal rate reflective of our volume.****

**UPDATE 4**

I have reasearched Open WRT and other solutons. I came upon [PF Sense](http://www.pfsense.org/) looks perfect!. Thoughts? I have an old P4 I can use. Then Just need a few compatible network cards :).

**Resolved:**

Modified network layout.

RV042 supports 1:1 Nat

Isolated Wifi on 1:1 Nat using WRT54G

Using 2 nics on Exchange server

1:1  IP mapped to smtp and OWA etc. Other for network traffic.

Thanks all for their help and assistance with this issue.

Comment: A comment here from whoever voted down this question is appreciated. I can then make adjustments to make the question more clear and hopefully you will then vote it up. I feel this is a valid question other small businesses with limited resources may have.

Comment: I evened it out for you. I think your question is legitimate. I assume it was downvoted because the suggested solution is not really a solution. The real solution is to keep your network secure, not implement a workaround for when your security is compromised. Asking for alternatives was a good idea. Hence my +1 :-)

Comment: I agree with you. But when all else fails (security, AV) the all the execs care about is continuing business. I agree with paying for what you get. But when it cuts into the bottom line a superhero will do. Unfortunately for them superheros are fiction. They will go with a let it happen then band aid while you heal it over spending money. I am embarrassed enough admitting we had a breach..

Comment: I really have no clue how your router works so its' hard to help.

Comment: I strongly recommend you get someone to come in and fix your problems as you are clearly not coping very well. Changing IP address or server is a temporary workaround, not a solution. The problems need to be fixed, not hidden.

Comment: @John The idea is to isolate while maintaining uptime if the situation repeated. Though we have taken proper measures now to eliminate that possibility. Moving Ips was required when we added more. Though the old IP had a lot of negative reputation attached to it from prior to my employment. Moving forward we will not see this repeat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I own Exchange 2003 server and have only been blacklisted once. You must be doing something wrong to get blacklisted so much. I've fixed it by doing following:

1. Using mxtoolbox to check my current server settings to see if IP is not blocked, and if Exchange is configured correctly (denying any sort of open gate). Create SPF record in DNS.
2. Put exchange incoming/outgoing connections going on IP that is only used by Exchange and nothing else.
3. Put users on different external IP (nat) and block port 25 on the firewall so users can't send any emails on 25th port. They can always use 587 and other SSL ports to send emails to their servers.

Those 3 rules should make it clear to get you running without spam problems. You can even go thru and unlist your already blacklisted IP's. MxToolBox will help you a lot with that.

Just to add, maybe you should get some help. Hire consultant or something. I can help if you would like some help.

To answer some of your questions asked:

1. You don't have to move users to new exchange or even setup additional exchange for that matter. You could just simply change it's IP or route to different IP address.
2. Some blacklists list ranges, especially dynamic ranges or ranges with high spam ratio. Some ranges are banned as dynamic even thought they are not, or banned because you have a spammy neighborhood. But not to worry. Usually you can just simply go to this spamlist and unlist your own IP or even make it whitelisted. But this is to be done only, and only if you know you are not sending spam anymore. If you do it before you will get blacklisted again and getting it done more times means harder to remove (or even impossible).

So my advice to you is clean your environment (you can check if you're still sending spam on spamlists since they usually give you ability to check last spam received from your IP - use that as part of your investigation), block 25 port, put exchange on different IP then other servers, users and check daily if you're doing OK. You can even set yourself on monitoring on MXToolBox to send you an email if any spam sending starts away.

Comment: This was a big help. i am doing a lot of this but a few are some good tips. The separate IP is happening ASAP now that I see the value :). THANKS!

Comment: Just saw your comment "Moved SMTP to non standard port. Explicitly blocked port 25 on firewall. delisted us.". Did you moved SMTP to different port on Exchange ? This won't work as emails will stop comming to your company. You need to block 25 port for everyone except your Exchange server and make sure your exchange server listens on 25. Otherwise you're gonna stop getting emails.

Comment: HEHE! Yah figured that out pretty quick. DONE AND DONE +1 Thanks!

Comment: OK! I am going to setup a second IP and put exchange on it. Now how do I connect the users on one IP to the server on the other IP? Do I just have the Exchange server have 2 IPs or is there more to it?

Comment: What Ip's did you give ? Like internal ip's ? or one external one internal?

Comment: Added an update :)

Comment: Your router is supposed to do all the work between one and the other subnet. You just need to set up your router properly to do the routing.

Comment: @MadBoy Update at the top :)

Answer (score 3):

You'll be much better off protecting your Exchange server, then trying to figure out how to migrate exchange on the fly.

Install some anti-virus software on your exchange server.
Secure your front end servers (the ones that have SMTP running and that the computers on the internet send email to) so that people can't send email via the server from outside your network.
Install some anti-virus software on all your servers and workstations.

Once all this is done you should be protected from spammers sending email through your servers and you should stop getting blacklisted.

Comment: Been done. still got infected. I would not be posing this question if we had not done this standard stuff first. I do appreciate the reply. We were infected on the main server. No one who is not authenticated can send mail through our SMTP. They installed their own.......

Comment: Sounds like a better anti-virus needs to be installed and more protections need to be put around the Exchange server so that the server can't be attacked again.

Comment: We use AVG it is very good. This attack happened after a Defrag is it possible this was the cause?

Comment: Are you sure you got reinfected? Maybe you never cleaned the original infection. Did you format and rebuild your Exchange servers? It's the only way to be sure you got it.

Comment: Yes reformat and rebuilt 198 days ago :(.

Comment: Have you identified how the virus is getting onto the server?  Is it coming from an outside threat or an internal users PC?  Are you blocking all ports from the outside to the exchange server except for 25 (and maybe 80/443 for OWA if on the same server)?

Comment: Working on this now @MrDenny I seem to be blocking everything now.... We were added back to a block list on the new IP. I See alot of Random IPs communicating with other Random Ips in my firewall logs.... Why would I see that?

Comment: @mrdenny UPDATE at the top :)

Comment: @Campo you shouldn't be seeing a lot of random traffic.  If you are, you may want to block it.  Sounds like things have started to come under control.

Comment: Update at the top :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're putting too many eggs in the wrong basket. First thing's first: PROTECT YOUR NETWORK!

Get some sort of virus scanning going on at your gateway. An IPS at the same location would also be a great idea.

Put good antivirus software on all of your computers. I know we hate it (I hate it too), but it's a necessary evil. Anything that gets past your first line of defense should get caught by the AV.

Block outbound connections to port 25 from every computer except your Exchange servers. There's a reason why ISPs often do this. It's because it stops spam zombies dead. Can't do nothing if they can't connect on port 25.

Look into outbound email services. I'm a user of [Postini](http://www.postini.com) myself. For the price, it's well worth it. There are others as well. I think Trend Micro, AppRiver, and Exchange Defender all do this...probably many more...

As for your solution, definately maybe. Most blocklists will block single IP addresses. So if one gets blocked, you can switch to another. I assume, however, that there are blocklists that are smarter than that. I'm sure someone out there is blocking IP addresses in blocks. So I wouldn't rely on this as a real solution.

As far as moving people, you can always route email through another Exchange server without moving the mailboxes. There's nothing to say that just because a user's mailbox is on one server that all of their mail has to go out to the internet from the same server...just set it up in Exchange to all go through a clean server.

Comment: I would like to go with MXTOOLBOX solution of inbound and outbound filtering but the company is not willing to spend the money. They are looking for a free solution utilizing the licenses they currently own.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, I just mean this to be food for thought...  If your company isn't willing to spend the money on the tools required to do it right, perhaps they shouldn't be running a mail server?  How about outsourcing it to an Exchange hosting provider?  To make the obligatory car analogy: your management is kind of saying: Our race car crashes, killing the driver.  We don't want to spend money on seatbelts, what can we do to make re-training a replacement driver as easy as possible?  :-)

Comment: I agree completely. I will try the analogy with them.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @mrdenny above, also prohibit workstations from sending email outside of the company network.  The workstations should only be able to send email through the exchange server which will send the email out to the recipient.  Stop anonymous relaying on your exchange server, only allow secure connections and close port 25.  If you can, create the SPF records for your domain (http://www.openspf.org/). It also goes without saying to have antivirus software installed on your workstations and exchange server.

Comment: Thanks! all been done prior to getting infected and spamming :(.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can move to a different IP and server.  However, unless you track down the source of this, and prevent it from happening in the future, it will almost certainly happen again (and again :-).  The spam-fighters aren't clueless, expect this to only work for a little while before they implement a larger block and start contacting your upstream ISPs.

So, you **can** do this, but it shouldn't be your primary response to getting blacklisted.

Answer (score -2):

> 1.Is this possible?

Yes.

> 2.Will we just be blocked again? (let's assume we are not sending out
>   spam on the secondary server and IP)

Likeky your whole network and all netwroks assigned to you will be blocked at one time.

> 3.How can I accomplish moving the users from one exchange to the other.
>   Moving mailboxes takes a LONG time.
>   Both exchange servers are on site
>   (physically beside each other)

- Upgrade to Exchagne 2007 or higher
- Issue disappears.

Basically 2007+ allow you to have different roles for a server. Simply do not have mailboxes on your front end server, use it purely for email exchange. But then, with 2010 and not-stupid configuration you would not ever have the issue.

> 4.With email reputation as heavily weighted as it is. Is it reasonable to
>   expect email sent from the secondary
>   IP to reach the users Inbox?

Yes.

That said, I never had an issue with spam in 15 years from any of my servers. So, your problem is not the computer, your problem is an admin not able to secure something as simple as a dedicated SMTP sender.

Comment: I am the Admin, I have stated above my actions. If you feel they could have been improved please be more  specific. Thanks,